# Unwind Segue is not performing Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, stack-unwinding

Currently I've the following Error:

```
2014-07-17 19:53:49.600 mobile-app[14483:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate _perform:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-    2935.138/UIStoryboardUnwindSegueTemplate.m:78
2014-07-17 19:53:49.602 mobile-app[14483:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not find a view controller to execute unwinding for <OptionsTabBarViewController: 0x16d75ad0>'
```

I'm trying by Touch up Inside do a Segue to the  RootViewController and then perform a SelectedIndex:1;

I've the following Code on optionsTabBarViewController:

```
- (IBAction)cancelCall:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {

    [self setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

On the StoryBoard I've linked the ViewController with the Exit here is the image:
[image][image]

And This is How I call the Segue on the ViewController:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"history_vc" sender: self];
```

Don't understand why it is not performing the Segue and is giving me the Error shown below.

This is My NavigationController Hirarchy:
[image]

Comment: Please describe your controller hierarchy.

Comment: @rdelmar Added an Image to the Question...

Comment: I don't think you can unwind to a tab bar controller, because there was no forward segue from it to any of its content controllers (it's a relationship, not a segue).

Comment: @rdelmar I've done it with other ViewControllers. You have skype? this is really important for me.. :'(

Comment: You can contact me via email at rdelmar@comcast.net